# jQuery is not undefined, but I can't use it?

Tags: jquery

I use a function to check if jQuery exist or not in my website! Well, the first lines are :

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    // it doesnt exist. I load it
} else {
    console.log($);
    $(document).ready(function() {
        startMyFunction();
    });
};
```

the problem is that, when I load the page, jQuery is not undefined, so it go directly to the else statment (I see the console.log message).

But, seems that I can't use it. `console.log($)` print `undefined`, and I get `$ is not a function` when the `$(document).ready` is called.

How is possible?

Comment: Are you loading jQuery asynchronously? What version are you using?

Comment: Post the contents of your `<head>` tag or, if you have them, the `<script>` tags at the bottom of your `<body>` tag.

Comment: ? I check if the website contains jQuery (don't care now about what version it is). Else, I load it asynchronously (but is not that the problem, because in fact it doesnt enter on `if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {`, which means it exist

Comment: Jquery is Not Defined then how it goes to else condition?

Comment: What happens if you use jQuery(document) instead of $(document) ?

Comment: @bharathi : is what I'd like to know!!!!

Comment: What other libraries are you loading? Have you tried doing `console.log(jQuery);` in your `else` block?

Comment: @arkascha : if I use jQuery(document) it seems to works...uhm?

Comment: @Gromer : as I said, console.log(jQuery); seems to works. I Think $ is in conflicts with other libraries? How can I resolve it?

Comment: Well, read a little about "conflicts" and "jQuery"...

Comment: It works fine http://jsfiddle.net/UjRms/4/ .

Comment: Ok, fixed! `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { startMyFunction($); });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `jQuery` exists but not `$`, you have probably loaded jQuery in `noconflicts` mode.

Comment: So, how can I must do? Can't manipulate the previous library, is not my control.

Comment: Ok, fixed! `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { startMyFunction($); });`

Comment: @markzzz: yeah, exactly like that. if you need to set `$` to be `jQuery` for a given scope, but have to run jQuery in noconflicts mode for compatibility purposes, you can define a closure and pass `jQuery` to it: `(function($) { all of your jQuery code using $ here })(jQuery);`